div element with :before pseudo class isn't shown on mobile phones
I was making the website responsive and it turned out one of the elements(the wavy line) is not displaying on mobile phones. However it displays when i check mobile sizes on devtools.
Here is my code:


.wavy-line {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.wavy-line:before {
  content: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  color: transparent;
  width: calc(100% + 27px);
  font-size: 45px;
  text-decoration: wavy #194027 underline;
  animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: -0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -45px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: -0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -45px;
  }
}

.wavy-line-green:before {
  text-decoration-color: #194027;
}
<div class="wavy-line wavy-line-green"></div>



i didn't change anything on mediaqueries
and here is link to my website also:
https://daryna-budz.github.io/tantillo/
ty in advance!
I tried to change the width and display properties but it does nothing

It's often worth using https://caniuse.com/ to check whether a property is suported.
In this case you'll see that -webkit- is needed e.g. for IOS to implement text-decoration.
This snippet adds this and it seems to work (tested on iPad IOS 16 Safari).


.wavy-line {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.wavy-line:before {
  content: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  color: transparent;
  width: calc(100% + 27px);
  font-size: 45px;
  -webkit-text-decoration: wavy #194027 underline;
  text-decoration: wavy #194027 underline;
  animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: -0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -45px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: -0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -45px;
  }
}

.wavy-line-green:before {
  text-decoration-color: #194027;
}
<div class="wavy-line wavy-line-green"></div>



